# What's the hook and double hook meaning in wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

What's the hook and double hook meaning in wireshark?

[image]

[image]

you see the two snapshots up there, when I select #7 the #6 will be hooked. 
when I select the #8, the #5 will be double hooked.

What's the meaning of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single check mark is the ACKnowledgement for the selected packet (obviously you've got an ordering problem here). The double check mark is a duplicate acknowledgment for the selected packet.

You can find out all about Wireshark's *Packet List Pane* in the help *3.17 The "Packet List" Pane*.

Comment: You see the time order problem, is it mean maybe this is a ACK attack?

Comment: That's a completely different question and impossible to answer without much more information (unlikely IMHO).